# GNUBG configure: error: You need to have glib2 to compile GNU backgammon

Tags: libraries

I do have it my system says `Package glib2-2.26.1-3.el6.i686 already installed and latest version`

I'm just trying to get an open source backgammon or chess game working on centos 6.5 32 bit system and not having much luck.

So I followed [this](http://gnubg.org/index.php?itemid=100&catid=10)

But many of those libraries must be wrong for my system because they come up as no package available but i did get the basic ones and I was able to command  `./autogen.sh` but with configure command it says I need glib2 which i already have. So why would it say I need it when it is already installed?

Perhaps someone else is having same problems as I am with repositories.

Comment: What OS is this? Check if a binary package of gnubg is available for your OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compile it then you need `glib2-devel` package.

Comment: you are right , thanks - can you tell me now i have run configure, make and make install and i have it residing in /usr/local/games how i can direct it so can open on my server please?

Comment: don't know what "run gnubg directly from the alt+f2 run window." means

Comment: @cea it assumes you have desktop environment like Gnome, KDE or Xfce (there's many of them) on your machine. These DEs use Alt+F2 to open dialog where you can launch arbitrary application (instead of launching it from terminal or from menu).

Comment: Oh so why can't I install KDE on my remote server and somehow open it that way? I want to play it with friends on my site.